# Why not just use https when sending username and password?

Tags: encryption, https

I am reading about various algorithms in javascript to encrypt username and passwords before sending to the server (so they cannot be read on the network).

I have seen demos where plain text is used for the password and the author has simply said 'in production I would use https as I would never send plain text'.

Not being a web developer, should I think about https or think about encrypting the information (username/password) I send?
Are the costs involved in setting up HTTPS that forces users not to use it? I know that once https is in place, everything is secure.

I guess I a missing some theory on the benefits of https and how it ties in with encryption for username/password.

Comment: HTTPS is the only real way to protect username and password. Of course you can add further encryption on top of that.

Comment: javascript encryption, i won't rely on that, its client side. Just check how https works :) http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13688/my-understanding-of-how-https-works-gmail-for-example